# Weird syntax error with semicolon in SCSS and Intellij IDEA

Tags: sass

I've tried to write SCSS in my Maven project with React in IDEA. I have sass and sass-loader in npm packages. But I always get a weird error:

[Syntax error: missing semicolon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOJWt.png)

This is a very simple scss example for test. I can't use other tag selectors as well. I've added scss variable on the top to see if it causes an error but it doesn't and all the errors stop at tags. I think that means that scss file is readable after all. And everything is ok when using just css. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Maybe someday it would be useful for somebody.

The point is I missed restarting webpack when changing it. I found configs for `sass-loader` on its npm page and added it to my `webpack.config.js` and then run `webpack --watch --progress`. Everything finally worked